# Fetching Data from remote Riak client using Python

Tags: python, riak

I am very new to `Riak` and would like to fetch the data from a remote `Riak` db using `Python`.

I installed the Riak client

- Step 1.easy_install riak
- Step 2.pip install riak

When I run a test page with import riak it works.
But

```
from riak import RiakClient, RiakNode
client = RiakClient(host='<ip>', protocol='pbc', pb_port=8078)
```

I get the error

> "ImportError: cannot import name RiakClient"

Can someone please help me to solve this.

Comment: is the name of your python script `riak.py`?

Comment: It works for me with either type of import.  Perhaps the filename of your script conflicts with one from the library?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for the reply in fact my filename was riak_fetchdata.py but I changed it to fetchdata.py but still I get this error.

Comment: As a troubleshooting step, try `from riak import *` and check what RiakClient refers to.  Perhaps there is a name conflict somewhere.